# backbone.js model.fetch sends no data to php

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

I'm just starting to play around with backbone.js to learn more about it for a project where I use Javascript for client side code an PHP on the server side.

To find out how communications between backbone and the server actually works (can't really find any good documentation about it. I just made a small example for `fetch()`:

```
var NavigationElement = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    defaults:   {
                    text: 'Home',
                    link: '/',
                    category: 'Main'
                },
    url: 'ajax.php'

});
var forum = new NavigationElement( { text: 'Forum', 
                                     link: '?q=Forum'});
var login = new NavigationElement( { text: 'Login', 
                                     link: '?q=Login', 
                                     category: 'User'});

forum.fetch();
```

Now, Backbone should send some `GET` data to the server to identify the data it has to send. And indeed, `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ]` says there is a GET-Request, but `$_GET` remains empty.

For `save()` I had a similar problem and learned, that I could find the data in `php://input` for all `POST` and `PUT` Requests. Is there a similar stream for `GET` Requests?

And how can I tell Backbone to send a GET-Request like `'.../ajax.php?model=NavigationElement&text=Login' ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [`model.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) will use the first available in

- the url attribute passed in the options to `fetch`
- what is set by `model.url`
- `model.urlRoot` with `/id` appended if the `id` attribute exists
- `model.collection.url` with `/id` appended if the `id` attribute exists

You can provide a custom `url` method on `NavigationElement` to set a different endpoint. For example:

```
var NavigationElement = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    defaults: {
        text: 'Home',
        link: '/',
        category: 'Main'
    },
    url: function() {
        return 'ajax.php?model=NavigationElement&text='+encodeURIComponent(this.get('text'));
    }
});
```

A demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ygdbxn1q/

or if you just want to pass additional parameters on `read` operations, you can override `fetch` and pass the data as an option:

```
var NavigationElement = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    defaults: {
        text: 'Home',
        link: '/',
        category: 'Main'
    },
    url: 'ajax.php',
    fetch: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.data = _.extend({
            model: 'NavigationElement'
        }, this.pick('text'));
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ygdbxn1q/1/